# Exposing inline images to Views

Tags: views, wysiwyg, media

I'm using Media module to insert inline images in the nodes body through the wysiwyg.

I'm trying to make an Views slideshow to list all these images and I've been banging my head at Views interface for the past hours, trying to find the related field which should be included but I can't find anything.

Is this simply not possible? If that's the case is there any Views plugin/add-on that can do the job?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

If an image is inserted into a textarea like your wysiwyg editor, the node does not retain an entity relationship with that image, you would need to parse the full content of that field for images, figure out if they are internal, get their ID...

Your node should ideally have a field of type image, that way your saved node has an association with one or more images you have uploaded. You can then insert the images inline wherever you wish.

Comment: It looks like you could use the [File Ownage](http://drupal.org/project/file_ownage) module to scan for inline images, and attach them to the node, which should then make the images available to Views. I haven't used the module yet, so this is a theoretical solution.

Comment: @Duncanmoo: After going through database tables I came to the same conclusions. After some negotiations with the content editors I was able to convince them to use the Insert Module which does the job of inline images and allows me to bend them in Views.

Keva: Thank you for pointing out that module. Although I won't use it this time, it is going directly on my bookmarks.

Comment: Wow @keva I did not know about that module, have not tested it but it addresses this very issue, which is such a _common_ problem.